# не подключиться к apache kafka после добавления еще одного брокера

Tags: golang, apache-kafka

Запускаю брокеры кафка в docker .
Через docker-compose создаю контейнеры с кафкой зукипером и другими сервисами взаимодействующими с кафкой.
Каждый брокер кафка и зукипер в отдельном контейнере.

Web ui для kafka (akhq.io) видит оба брокера.

Но подключиться из сервиса на golang не получается.
с одним брокером все работало.
Использую библиотеку github.com/segmentio/kafka-go

Пытаюсь подключиться через Dial , но получаю panic

```
 func listTopics() map[string]struct{} {

    conn, err := kafka.Dial("tcp", conf.Config.APP.KafkaBrokerAddress)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    partitions, err := conn.ReadPartitions()
    if err != nil {
        return m
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    for _, p := range partitions {
        if _, exist := m[p.Topic]; exist == false {
            m[p.Topic] = struct{}{}
        }
    }
    return m
}
```

Если в метод Dial передаю kafka-0:29092,kafka-1:29072  либо kafka-0:9092,kafka-1:9072

> Получаю panic:   dial tcp: lookup kafka-0:29092,kafka-1:29072: Try  again
> либо    dial tcp: lookup kafka-0:9092,kafka-1:9072: Try again

Если в Dial передаю адрес одного сервиса с  брокером кафка
kafka-0:29092 либо kafka-0:9092

> То panic : dial tcp: 127.0.0.1:9072 connection refused либо dial tcp:
> 127.0.0.1:9092 connection refused

Dial нельзя передавать несколько адресов брокеров? или в чем проблема?

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  zookeeper-data-0:
    driver: local
  zookeeper-log-0:
    driver: local
  kafka-data-0:
    driver: local
  kafka-data-1:
    driver: local

services:
    akhq-panel: #akhq.io
        image: tchiotludo/akhq
        environment:
          AKHQ_CONFIGURATION: |
            micronaut:
              security:
                enabled: true
            akhq:
              security:
                default-group: no-roles
                basic-auth: #Password in sha256
                  - username: admin
                    password: password
                    groups: # Groups for the user
                      - admin
              connections:
                docker-kafka-server-1:
                  properties:
                    bootstrap.servers: "kafka-0:29092,kafka-1:29072"
                  schema-registry:
                    url: "http://schema-registry-0:8085"
        ports:
          - 8888:8080
        depends_on:
          - kafka-0
          - kafka-1
          - schema-registry-0

    zookeeper:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
      volumes:
        - zookeeper-data-0:/var/lib/zookeeper/data:Z
        - zookeeper-log-0:/var/lib/zookeeper/log:Z
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: '2181'
        ZOOKEEPER_ADMIN_ENABLE_SERVER: 'false'

    kafka-0:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
      volumes:
        - kafka-data-0:/var/lib/kafka:Z
      ports:
        - 9092:9092
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: '0'
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
        KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: '12'
        KAFKA_COMPRESSION_TYPE: 'gzip'
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: '1'
        KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
        KAFKA_JMX_PORT: '9091'
        KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
        KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: 'kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer'
        KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: 'true'
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://kafka-0:29092,EXTERNAL://kafka-0:9092'
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://kafka-0:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092'
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT'
        KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'INTERNAL'
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper

    kafka-1:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
      volumes:
        - kafka-data-1:/var/lib/kafka:Z
      ports:
        - 9072:9072
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: '1'
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
        KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: '12'
        KAFKA_COMPRESSION_TYPE: 'gzip'
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: '1'
        KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
        KAFKA_JMX_PORT: '9071'
        KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
        KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: 'kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer'
        KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: 'true'
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://kafka-1:29072,EXTERNAL://kafka-1:9072'
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://kafka-1:29072,EXTERNAL://localhost:9072'
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT'
        KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'INTERNAL'
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper

    schema-registry-0:
      image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
      ports:
        - 8085:8085
      depends_on:
        - kafka-0
        - kafka-1
      environment:
        SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka-0:29092'
        SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: 'schema-registry-0'
        SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: 'http://schema-registry-0:8085'
        SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: 'INFO'

    adapter: #kafka adapter
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./adapter.dockerfile
        environment:
            - GO_ENV=dev
            - GOPATH=/go
        container_name: kafka-adapter
        depends_on:
          - kafka-0
          - kafka-1version: '3'

volumes:
  zookeeper-data-0:
    driver: local
  zookeeper-log-0:
    driver: local
  kafka-data-0:
    driver: local
  kafka-data-1:
    driver: local

services:
    akhq-panel: #akhq.io
        image: tchiotludo/akhq
        environment:
          AKHQ_CONFIGURATION: |
            micronaut:
              security:
                enabled: true
            akhq:
              security:
                default-group: no-roles
                basic-auth: #Password in sha256
                  - username: admin
                    password: password
                    groups: # Groups for the user
                      - admin
              connections:
                docker-kafka-server-1:
                  properties:
                    bootstrap.servers: "kafka-0:29092,kafka-1:29072"
                  schema-registry:
                    url: "http://schema-registry-0:8085"
        ports:
          - 8888:8080
        depends_on:
          - kafka-0
          - kafka-1
          - schema-registry-0

    zookeeper:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
      volumes:
        - zookeeper-data-0:/var/lib/zookeeper/data:Z
        - zookeeper-log-0:/var/lib/zookeeper/log:Z
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: '2181'
        ZOOKEEPER_ADMIN_ENABLE_SERVER: 'false'

    kafka-0:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
      volumes:
        - kafka-data-0:/var/lib/kafka:Z
      ports:
        - 9092:9092
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: '0'
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
        KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: '12'
        KAFKA_COMPRESSION_TYPE: 'gzip'
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: '1'
        KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
        KAFKA_JMX_PORT: '9091'
        KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
        KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: 'kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer'
        KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: 'true'
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://kafka-0:29092,EXTERNAL://kafka-0:9092'
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://kafka-0:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092'
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT'
        KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'INTERNAL'
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper

    kafka-1:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
      volumes:
        - kafka-data-1:/var/lib/kafka:Z
      ports:
        - 9072:9072
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: '1'
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
        KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: '12'
        KAFKA_COMPRESSION_TYPE: 'gzip'
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: '1'
        KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
        KAFKA_JMX_PORT: '9071'
        KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
        KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: 'kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer'
        KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: 'true'
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://kafka-1:29072,EXTERNAL://kafka-1:9072'
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://kafka-1:29072,EXTERNAL://localhost:9072'
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT'
        KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'INTERNAL'
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper

    schema-registry-0:
      image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
      ports:
        - 8085:8085
      depends_on:
        - kafka-0
        - kafka-1
      environment:
        SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka-0:29092'
        SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: 'schema-registry-0'
        SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: 'http://schema-registry-0:8085'
        SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: 'INFO'

    adapter: #kafka adapter
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./adapter.dockerfile
        environment:
            - GO_ENV=dev
            - GOPATH=/go
        container_name: kafka-adapter
        depends_on:
          - kafka-0
          - kafka-1
```

Comment: по этому адресу кафка недоступна. проверьте ее доступность для начала

Comment: Почему в первом случае у вас используются имена `kafka-0` и `kafka-1`? Эти dns-имена точно существуют? Go не может их зарезолвить из-за чего выдает ошибку.. Во втором случае - у вас в ошибке жестко указан порт 9092 - почему в первом примере использовались другие порты (29092 и 29097)? Go не может к нему подключится, поэтому и выдает ошибку - проверьте что порт корректен и открыт на вашей машине.

Comment: kafka-0 kafka-1 это адреса контейнеров docker, с брокерами kafka.          
 С одним брокером, все прекрасно работает.                         docker-compose.yaml добавил .

Comment: Судя по документации метод Dial() принимает только один адрес. И это должен быть адрес брокера, который является лидером.

Comment: Объединил контейнеры в одну сеть. С двумя адресами брокеров через запятую , подключиться не могу. Но если попробовать подключиться , то с вероятностью 50% у все корректно заработает и топики создадутся.    Так как мне нужно подключиться к лидеру . если не угадал адрес лидера, то получаю connection refused сразу же

Comment: перезапускаю до тех пор пока не подключусь в лидеру

Comment: Для этого zookeeper и используется, нужно на него делать запрос для проверки [брокеров](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70427334/kafka-leader-none-and-kafka-broker-id-not-signed-in-zookeeper) и получения [конфигурации](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743769/why-does-a-kafka-cluster-need-a-controller-when-it-already-uses-zookeeper) для лидера.